# Adding a Prefix to the End of a URL Using Mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I`m working on making a Simple URL Shortener But having some Issues with Mod_Rewrite ~

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^hu/([^/]*)$ /?code=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^AgeofW\.us$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^hu/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/hu/$1 [R=301]
```

The Idea of the URL is "AgeofW.us/hu/" to have a Trailing /hu/ at the end of the URL no matter what. But again. I`m having some Issues with this. I`ve tried for the last hour or two, and I have been forced to ask here! Anyone have a Idea? Or Explain to me? I`ll memorize it Lolz.

~~ This Generates a Infinite Loop that Generates: The requested URL /hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/ was not found on this server. ~ Over and Over again.

I`ve multiple Attempts, and Code Corrections, and have yet to comeup with a single Viable Solution.

Comment: When you have problems with code, (1) post your code (✓), (2) have a clear description of what you expect the code to do (more or less here) and (3) tell us exactly what the current code is doing (totally missing). Please edit your question and edit in the missing information.

Comment: The Title Explains EXACTELY wht the issue is. The Description is there, Explaining the Issue as well. And the CODE itself is right there infront of you. Dont downvote a Question, cause your eye sight is bad.

Comment: Your problem description was "Im having some Issues with this". That is logical. You wouldn't post here if your code is doing what you expect it to do. It is not a good problem description though. A good problem description describes what you see on your screen, for example that you get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/hu/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} AgeofW\.us$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^hu/ /hu%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^hu/([^/]*)/?$ /?code=$1 [L,QSA]
```

1. In general keep redirect rules before rewrite ones.
2. `[^hu/]` is not correct regex to match `not hu/`.

Comment: The requested URL /hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/ Is the Response of that.

Comment: `RewriteRule !^hu/` will not add `/hu/` if it is already there. Can you test this in a new browser.

Comment: @BioblazePayne: Try it one more time with latest updates to the rules.

Comment: @Sumurai8: Please elaborate why it would cause infinite loop. I will be happy to correct it.

Comment: The requested URL /hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/hu/ was not found on this server. ~ Same issue. It creates a infinite loop. This is the exacte same issue i`ve been having. No idea why. I know the L Flag is for the Loop, but I cant figure out why it genertes the max /hu for the loop.

Comment: Its funny, several billion people on the Planet, I`m sure someone else is having the same Issue I am. But they simply dont post on here. ~ The Issue is not Fixed, I`ve updated the Code. That was posted, and it hasnt fixed anything.

Comment: This rule is not looping unless you have some code/rule removing `/hu/` from the URLs. Do you have more rules or is this the only code?

Comment: Also make sure to test it in a new browser again.

Comment: @BioblazePayne http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156093/mod-rewrite-with-external-redirect-and-internal-rewrite http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197749/mod-rewrite-error-310-too-many-redirects

Comment: Ok I`ve Opened it in a new Browser, and it works. ~ Updating the Post, with Information. And going to Mark it as Solved. Give me some Time. :)